# How do I add a font to a label with multiple properties?

Tags: c#, forms

I'm currently trying to generate labels at runtime, and also add their respective font at runtime.

So far I managed to get my label underlined and bold with this line:

```
championName.Font = new Font(championName.Font, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline);
```

Even though adding up attributes with | also seems quite odd already, it works.

However, if I now want to change my labels text size as well, how would I do that? I can't quite figure out where I would have to squeeze that in.

I tried to do it by creating a font object like this:

```
Font fnt = new Font();
```

and then editing its properties, but that failed pretty quick considering I can't just create an object like that.

So, how would I change multiple things at this label at once? I mean it's pretty obvious I can't just assign another `new Font();` without losing my old one, so there has to be a way to do it.

Comment: The `Font` constructor has an overload that takes a font size: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zet4c3fa(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The next thing you will want are colors; so create a class and put stuff in it.. Such a myFont instance can also be stored in the Labels' Tags.

Comment: "Even though adding up attributes with | also seems quite odd already" - it's a bitwise or; each enum value represents a certain bit pattern (e.g. 0001 and 0010), and by bitwisely ORing them, you get a bit pattern that encompasses *both* attribute (0011).

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes but it does not take an existing font, only a font style or name, so you'd have to set the other properties as well.  OP seems to be looking to only change the size.

Comment: @DStanley yes, but you can easily get the font name from an existing font (`championName.Font.FontFamily`) as the accepted answer says.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [System.Drawing.Font class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a couple of contructors. One possibility would be to use one of the constructor with [`size` parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141987%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
championName.Font = new Font(SystemFonts.DefaultFont, 16.0, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline);
// championName.Font = new Font(championName.Font.FontFamily, 16.0, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline);
```

Comment: You could also alter the current font by using it as the first argument.

Comment: @LeeHarrison I have updated my example code. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I don't know why I can't get this to work. According to the Doc this seems like it should work. However, it's always suggesting me the closest accordance would be Font.Font(string familyName, float emSize, GraphicsUnit unit).

Comment: Have a look at [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Try changing `championName.Font` to `championName.Font.FontFamily`.

Comment: I'm glad that the answer helped.

Answer (score 2):

Try these couple of solutions:

1) You can try the overloaded constructors of the `Font` class. Some of them include the size as one of the parameters. See the documentation for the constructors here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.font(v=vs.110).aspx

Example:

```
new Font("font-family", 1.5F, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline);
```

2) You can try accessing the `Size` property of the `Font` property of the `Label` like this:

```
championName.Font.Size = 1.5F;
```

Let me know your findings.